# I have simply no idea what happened here, I used fontawesome

Tags: html, css, font-size, font-awesome-5

[Screenshot of the Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKr1k.png)

After formatting a few things in the section before (which should absoloutely not have an impact on this section) this just happened. The font-size on all of the names is 4em (h4). But somehow it is displayed as different sizes. It screwed up my spacing and placed this icon everywhere.

I am completely baffeled by what could have caused this.

```
<section class="panel configuration" data-section-name="configuration">
<div class="inner">
<h2>Unser Team</h2>
<p><b>Wir sind im Grunde Ihre Lieblingsleute, die auch tolle Webseiten erstellen, Logos entwerfen und Ihnen helfen, Ihr Geschäft bekannt zu machen, wir sind uns sicher, dass Sie uns mögen werden.</b></p>

<div class="rowz">
        <div class="windowz" style="background: linear-gradient(#ffffff2c, #ffffff05)">
                <div>
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%" src="img/avatar-2.jpg" width="150" height="150">
                    <h4>Luan B</h4>
                    <h3>Gründer und Designer</h3>
                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></i><i class="fas fa-file-code"></i>
                  </div>
            </div>

<div class="windowz" style="background: linear-gradient(#ffffff2c, #ffffff05)">
                <div>
                    <img style="border-radius: 50%" src="img/avatar-1.jpg" width="150" height="150">
                    <h4>Loris K</h4>
                    <h3>Designer</h3>
                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i> <i class="fas fa-swatchbook"></i>
                  </div>
            </div>

    <div class="windowz" style="background: linear-gradient(#ffffff2c, #ffffff05)">
        <div>
            <img style="border-radius: 50%" src="img/avatar-3.jpg" width="150" height="150">
            <h4>Lino P</h4>
            <h3>Backend-Developer</h3>
            <i class="far fa-file-code"></i> <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
    </div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thats the section.
I would appreciate the help a lot. 
Thanks in advance.

PS the normal title and general fonts shouldn't be this big either

Comment: There's nothing in your code which controls either font sizes or spacing.

Comment: Sure - introducing anything like FontAwesome ... or Bootstrap ... or *ANY* new/changed/additional CSS could potentially "mess things up".  SUGGESTION: Use Google Developer Tools, and analyze the difference with/without FontAwesome for the HTML elements you're interested in.  Here's a good tutorial (you can find many with a Google search):  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/beginners/css

Comment: I noticed in the first line that uses a font awesome icon. You have two `</i>` closing tags. That could mess up the rest of your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a mistake in the code. You have double < /i > closing tags in the first 'windowz' block. Remove one closing i tag and it should work.

Comment: What should work exactly? There are no open <i> blocks - a wrong closing tag will be ignored by the browser

Answer (score 1):

The Mistake was double `</i>`

```html
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></i>
```

Instead of

```html
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
```